# Inserting values into a column by derived from another column in the same table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two columns in a table:

- FlightNumber (which has values such as AI-1234, AI-3242), and
- FlightId (which is supposed to be 1234, 3242 based on the FlightNumber)

I am able to select the FlightNumber column with last 4 characters of each record.

```
 SELECT RIGHT(flightnumber, 4) FROM pnrdetails
```

But I am not sure how to insert this into the FlightId column.  Suggestions?

Comment: What happens if the format of your flightnumbers change e.g. to 5 digits or drop to 3 in between? What you are trying to achieve is extracting the numeric part of your flight number. I would do this by either extracting everything to the right of the dash or all digits at the right side of the flight number (i.e. scanning right to left until the first nondigit character is encounted).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess , you dont need insert. you should be thinking about update.
and I assume `FlightId` datatype is `int`.

```
 update pnrdetails set FlightId = convert(int,RIGHT(flightnumber, 4));
```

Answer (score 0):

you could update the table

```
update pnrdetails
set FlightId =RIGHT(flightnumber, 4)
```